# 3D variography: rotation matrices for multiple angles support

Tags: 3d, rotate, variogram

I'm currently working on a 3D variogram algorithm based on [geostatsmodels](https://github.com/cjohnson318/geostatsmodels) (which only handles 2D datasets). I'm having a hard time understanding how to have rotation along the z-axis for azimuth direction handling to work.

From the sources available online that implement 2D directional variograms ([scikit-gstat](https://github.com/mmaelicke/scikit-gstat/blob/master/skgstat/DirectionalVariogram.py), [pyGeoStatistics](https://github.com/whimian/pyGeoStatistics/blob/master/pygeostatistics/gamv.py)), I understand that I need to apply rotation matrices to the found paired vectors.

Currently, I'm computing the initial vector (difference of two points in space) then applying the 3D rotation matrices ([Rotation Matrix on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations)), then computing the new angles from the rotated coordinates.

But I'm still facing differences in my variogram compared to what I compute in R, when changing the azimuth angle along the z-axis (for exemple east direction, ie 90 degrees). Probably because the new angles are incorrect.

For the moment I only use the "yaw" matrix for horizontal rotation:

[image: rotation_matrix]

I wanted to know if this approach seems correct, and if yes, if I was rightly considering the good matrix ?